# Tomcat not Restarting :: Syntax error on line 106 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

When i logged into my remote system (Amazon Linux) after executing apache2 recipe, the httpd service was running, i checked it by using `service httpd status`, then i wrote `service httpd restart` after that service stopped but didnt restart. It gives me following error.

```
[root@java-app1 webapps]# sudo service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 106 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/mods-enabled/systemd.load: Cannot load /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_systemd.so into server: /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_systemd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Comment: and nothing was changed in between?

Comment: Does the file exist? If not you might have a mismatch between expected version and what is available for Amazon Linux.

Comment: @TJ- ya i edited the index.html file.

Comment: which file ? @coderanger

Comment: `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_systemd.so`, as stated in the error message.

Comment: @coderanger ya u were right.Its not there. As per my understanding the expected version is what we mention in the metadata file. and also the in the recipes author mention the version of the recipe, so how can they mismatch ? please correct me if i am wrong. also if that is the case then how will i know the version of apache2 that amazon linux is expecting .

Comment: i found the way how to find the version mismatch between the two. thanks @coderanger for your patience !