# Mismatch between expected version of apache2 and what is available for Amazon Linux

Tags: apache, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I was going through a question at stack overflow and found a comment mentioning the problem could be because of  mismatch between expected version of apache2 and what is available for Amazon Linux. I was wondering How to find this ?

**The Question**

> [Tomcat not Restarting :: Syntax error on line 106 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222925/tomcat-not-restarting-syntax-error-on-line-106-of-etc-httpd-conf-httpd-conf?noredirect=1#comment42926097_27222925)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, i found a way for that (i do not know if its the optimal or not).
Start your instance (the layer should be java app ) and remotely log in the instance(by using putty or some other tool), then at the terminal write `httpd -V`, and it will tell you the version for that. in my case it was 2.2.29. This way you can know the expected version of apache2 on the default java app server layer.

please do not accept is as correct answer now. wait for some more answers and see if they make more sense because i do not think it's an optimal way for that, it's just a workaround.